# term document matrix using apache spark mllib library

Tags: apache-spark

Thanks in advance..I need to create a term document matrix using apache spark ... Can any one tell me how I can to that using java mllib library of spark.Also can we implement affinity propagation algorithm using mllib.

Answer (score 2):

For document classification in Spark have a look at Naive Bayes
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html

You may also want to have a look at the TF-IDF method
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following [blog](https://davefernig.com/2016/05/07/building-a-term-document-matrix-in-spark/) for details. Here's a summary:

```
sc = SparkContext('local', 'term_doc')
corpus = sc.parallelize([
    "It is the east, and Juliet is the sun.",
    "A dish fit for the gods.",
    "Brevity is the soul of wit."])

tokens = corpus.map(lambda raw_text: raw_text.split()).cache()   
local_vocab_map = tokens.flatMap(lambda token: token).distinct()\
                        .zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()

vocab_map = sc.broadcast(local_vocab_map)
vocab_size = sc.broadcast(len(local_vocab_map))

term_document_matrix = tokens \
 .map(Counter) \
 .map(lambda counts: {vocab_map.value[token]: float(counts[token]) for token in counts})\
 .map(lambda index_counts: SparseVector(vocab_size.value, index_counts))

for doc in term_document_matrix.collect():
    print doc`
```

This will produce the following output:

```
>>> tokens.first()
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east,', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun.']

>>> local_vocab_map
{'and': 0, 'A': 1, 'fit': 14, 'for': 13, 'of': 3, 'is': 4, 'gods.': 7, 'It': 11,\
'Brevity': 10, 'soul': 12, 'sun.': 8, 'dish': 2, 'east,': 9, 'the': 5, 'wit.': 6, 'Juliet': 15}

>>> for doc in term_document_matrix.collect():
        print doc
(16,[0,4,5,8,9,11,15],[1.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
(16,[1,2,5,7,13,14],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
(16,[3,4,5,6,10,12],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```